# beautifulsoup4: placing a for loop unwrapping tags into a definition (python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

How could I put this for loop into a definition?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html="<p>ABC <i>Italic1 </i><i>Italic2</i></p>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")

for i in soup.findAll('i'): 
        soup.i.unwrap()
print(soup)
```

I did try that but without success:

```
def UnwrapTag(x):
    x=str(x)
    for x in soup.findAll(x):   
            soup.x.unwrap()  #wrong but what else?

UnwrapTag('i')
```

Comment: `i` and `x` are the loop variables, not `soup.i` or `soup.x`.

Comment: @poke the first block work exactly as expected (`i` is a `bs4.element.Tag` and is referenced to `soup` so you can do `soup.i`, even though it's not needed)

Comment: @Dekel It has a very different meaning though. Using `soup.i` there, inside that loop, is just wrong.

Comment: @poke you'r right! updated my answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, actually you shouldn't use `soup.i` here.

`soup.i` means *The first `<i>` element inside the `soup` variable*.

Just because you used the same name - it worked. What you actually want to use is the `i` variable (and not `soup.i`).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html="<p>ABC <i>Italic1 </i><i>Italic2</i></p>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")

for i in soup.findAll('i'): 
        i.unwrap()
print(soup)
```

Same here:

```
def UnwrapTag(x):
    x=str(x)
    for x in soup.findAll(x):   
        x.unwrap()

UnwrapTag('i')
```

Comment: Thank you so much for for your explanation! I understand my mistake (and many others with that !)

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question of *what is wrong?* I think you are confusing the `x` using it as a var for the iterations  and as the parameter, with this code everything runs as the original code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html="<p>ABC <i>Italic1 </i><i>Italic2</i></p>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")

def UnwrapTag(x):
    #x=str(x) # no need to do this
    for k in soup.findAll(x):  # using k instead of x to catch values
        k.unwrap()  
    print(soup)

UnwrapTag('i')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def UnwrapTag(soup, target):  
    for x in soup.findAll(target):
        print(x.text)
```

test:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html="<p>ABC <i>Italic1 </i><i>Italic2</i></p>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
UnwrapTag(soup, 'i')
```

out:

```
Italic1 
Italic2
```

Comment: that's super interesting, I would not have thought of that, thanks a lot 宏杰李!